# JSON : fetch mapping data

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

**Summary :**

There are three `dropdowns` for each `levelNum`. such as dropdown for levelNum2 contains `(Department-Unit-1, Department-Unit-2 & Department-Unit-3)`,levelNum3 contains `(Division-Unit-1 & Division-Unit-2)` and levelNum4 contains `(Business-Unit-1 & Business-Unit-2)`.

There is an `array of objects`.Inside each object there is a property named **`hierarchyLevels`** which is again an `array of objects`.Inside each object there is a two property **`unitName`** & **`levelNum`** as shown in below `JSON`.

```
var data = [{
    "hierarchyLevels": [{
        "unitName": "Department-Unit-3",
        "levelNum": 2
    }, {
        "unitName": "Division-Unit-2",
        "levelNum": 3
    }, {
        "unitName": "Business-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 4
    }]
}, {
    "hierarchyLevels": [{
        "unitName": "Department-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 2
    }, {
        "unitName": "Division-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 3
    }, {
        "unitName": "Business-Unit-2",
        "levelNum": 4
    }]
}, {
    "hierarchyLevels": [{
        "unitName": "Department-Unit-2",
        "levelNum": 2
    }, {
        "unitName": "Business-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 4
    }]
}]
```

**Tried so far :**

```
function getMultipleObjectFromList(propertyName, value, list){
    return list.filter(function (item) {
        return item.hierarchyLevels.some(function (level) {
            return level[propertyName] === value;
        });
    });
};

var res = getMultipleObjectFromList('unitName','Business-Unit-1',data);
```

**Requirement :**

I want to `fetch` all `unitName` associated with another `unitName`. So, if I select `Business-Unit-1` from the `levelNum4` dropdown, the other low level dropdown will auto fill with `unitName` associated with `Business-Unit-1`.i.e `levelNum3` dropdown will contain only `Division-Unit-2` and `levelNum2` dropdown will contain `(Department-Unit-2 & Department-Unit-3)`.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen, i updated the question with `tried so far` section.

Comment: Does substituting `if(tempObj[propertyName] == value)` with `if(tempObj.hierarchyLevels[propertyName] === value)` solves your problem? In case it does not help, can you post how the result of your function should look like? What structure should the resulting object have?

Comment: 2 questions: 1. When you say `"the other low level dropdown"` you mean dropdowns with `levelNum` less than the selected one? 2. How do you determine the association between two or more `unitName`?

Comment: Any reason why levelNum starts at 2? Where is 1? Does your data structure have to be like this, or can we suggest a better one?

Comment: @iulian  I updated the question with result i want. check now

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen 1. Yes exactly, 2. That i want to know from you guys that how can i map one unitName with another unitName.

Comment: @trincot there is level1 also but i just put sample of the JSON here to sumarrize the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure has more levels than you treat in your function. There is the `hierarchyLevels` property which you omit, and it is an array, which you do not iterate.

Here is a proposed adapted function that returns those `hierarchyLevels` that match. I also add a similar function that returns the inner object when there is a match, instead of the `hierarchyLevels` array. That one can be used to populate your drop-downs:

```js
function getMultipleObjectFromList(propertyName, value, list){
    return list.filter(function (item) {
        return item.hierarchyLevels.some(function (level) {
            return level[propertyName] === value;
        });
    });
};

function getDetailFromList(propertyName, value, list){
    return list.map(function (item) {
        return item.hierarchyLevels.filter(function (level) {
            return level[propertyName] === value;
        }).pop(); // only return single match
    }).filter(function (item) { // exclude null
        return item;
    }); 
};


var data = [{
    "hierarchyLevels": [{
        "unitName": "Department-Unit-3",
        "levelNum": 2
    }, {
        "unitName": "Division-Unit-2",
        "levelNum": 3
    }, {
        "unitName": "Business-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 4
    }]
}, {
    "hierarchyLevels": [{
        "unitName": "Department-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 2
    }, {
        "unitName": "Division-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 3
    }, {
        "unitName": "Business-Unit-2",
        "levelNum": 4
    }]
}, {
    "hierarchyLevels": [{
        "unitName": "Department-Unit-2",
        "levelNum": 2
    }, {
        "unitName": "Business-Unit-1",
        "levelNum": 4
    }]
}];

var res = getMultipleObjectFromList('unitName','Business-Unit-1',data);

var level2 = getDetailFromList('levelNum', 2, res);

var level3 = getDetailFromList('levelNum', 3, res);

var output = '<h2>filtered data:</h2>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4) + '\n'
           + '<h2>level 2:</h2>' + JSON.stringify(level2, null, 4)  + '\n'
           + '<h2>level 3:</h2>' + JSON.stringify(level3, null, 4);

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: need your small help again..now i am facing problem with combination of two. now i want `levelNum2` object mapped with both (`levelNum3 and levelNum4`).Example : If i select `Business-Unit-2` from 1st dropdown and `Division-Unit-1` from second dropdown. Then third dropdown should only contain `Department-Unit-1` which is mapped with both.

Comment: just call `getMultipleObjectFromList` twice. First on `data`, and the second time on the result of the first call. Something like `res = getMultipleObjectFromList('unitName', 'Business-Unit-2', getMultipleObjectFromList('unitName', 'Division-Unit-1', data));` ... etc.